# Export a dynamic variable

Tags: node.js, promise, node-modules

I'm trying to export a variable in node.js like this:

```
let news = [];

const fetchNews = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

  let query = 'SELECT id, name FROM news';

  mysql.query(query, [], (error, results) => {

    if (error)
      reject({error: `DB Error: ${error.code} (${error.sqlState})`})

    results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));

    news = results;

    resolve(results);

  });

});

if(!news.length)
  fetchNews
    .then(results => {news = results})
    .catch(err => {console.log('Unable to fetch news', err)});

exports.news = news;
```

When I use this code in some other module like this:

```
const news = require('./news.js').news;

console.log(news);
//returns [];
```

Can somebody point out my mistake in first code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things that seem odd in the way you are doing this:

You have an async operation but you want just the value without actually awaiting on the operation to complete. Try something like this:

```
module.exports = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  mysql.query('SELECT id, name FROM news', (error, results) => {
    if (error)
      reject({error: `DB Error: ${error.code} (${error.sqlState})`})

    resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)));
  });
});
```

Then to get the news:

```
var getNewsAsync = require('./news')
getNewsAsync.then(news => console.log(news))
```

It would be cleaner/shorter if you actually utilize async/await with the `mysql` lib.

**Update**:

With [Node 8 and above you should be able to promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) the `mySQL` lib methods. Although there might be better npm options out there to get this to work. Here is an **untested** version:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({yourHOST/USER/PW/DB});
const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

module.exports = async () => {
  try {return await query('SELECT id, name FROM news')} finally {conn.end()}
}
```

To get the news:

```
var getNewsAsync = require('./news')
console.log(await getNewsAsync())
```

Comment: Can you please amend your answer to utilise async/await with the `mysql` lib?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Not tested however so you should experiment with it.